# How to set user created subdomain in vue?

Tags: vue.js, subdomain, vue-router

When a user adds a field called "myhome" to the 'domain' table in database,
myhome.companydomain.com
I want to make it accessible by myhome.companydomain.com

Is this possible?

I'm usind vue cli and vue router

Thank you.

Comment: subdomains is DNS, not clientside

Comment: @LawrenceCherone So what can I use to implement it? For example, should I use nginx?

Comment: one option is to use a catch-all in DNS i.e *.companydomain.com, and use nginx default server i.e `_` to your vue app

Comment: @LawrenceCherone you mean in nginx configuration like  server {  server_name _; } ?